# Why are there two black wires connected to the bottom of my three-way switch?

Tags: switch, multiway-switch

I am installing a new 3 way switch. When I open up the existing three way I see two back wires connected that the bottom, one black in the top and one white at the top.  Can someone advise what the two bottom is about?

[image: back of wire box]

[image]

Comment: One of the wires is probably running to a different switch, to feed it "hot".  Two separate circuits feeding from a common circuit breaker.

Comment: Top is for the 2 travelers, the two on the bottom is the output

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the back of the box please?

Comment: ThreePhaseEel.  I added picture of back it box.

Comment: The two at the top are a code violation, but you weren't asking about that.

Comment: This can't possibly be a legitimate three-way switch setup. There must be at least one /3 (three insulated current-carrying conductors) cable in the box. You only have /2s pictured. The uninsulated ground is being used to carry power, which is extremely dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

The black screw at the bottom of the switch is your common terminal. The common terminal either goes to the fixture being controlled or to the always hot that feeds the circuit. Since you've got two blacks connected to that terminal,one to the screw and one to its backstab, it's the always hot with a tap off to another device like an outlet or to another switch. Those two black wires should be pigtailed together with a small length of wire with a wire nut and connected  to the black screw on your new switch. The black wire and the white wire going to the other two screws are the traveler and would go to the other two screws on your switch, not to the black screw.